# C# Application_Idle does not fire when MessageBox or FileDialogue is active... Any alternates?

Tags: c#, messagebox

We have implemented Application_Idle event in our application. This works great, and users are promptly asked to enter the password if the session is idle for about 20 minutes.

However, if there is a **message-box** open or a **File Dialogue** open to Save/Open the file. Application_Idle never fires. Even if we leave the application idle overnight.

This is a big of a *security concern*. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the idle event use a timer that will lock the application after a configurable timeout. Needless to say, the timer needs to be reset, when the user is interacting with the application.

Comment: Thank you 0xA3. Your name sounds as if you are a Robot :)